# Trying to center a header on a button but it keeps being *slightly off-center

Tags: html, css, email

I'm working with this body of code, and it presents the header on a button slightly towards the right. I can't figure out if there's a mistake in the padding? The code:

```
<p style="margin:0;font-family:'montreal-mediumregular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Tahoma, 'Sans-Serif';color:rgb(70,82,118);font-size:18px;line-height:25px;padding:15px 0 0 0;text-align:center;">
          <br><a href="https://www.orderin.co.za/" style="color:#d3392c;font-size:18px;text-align:center;background:rgb(255,255,255);padding:10px;border:1px solid #d3392c;width:205px;margin:20px auto 20px;font-family:'montreal-demiboldregular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Tahoma, 'Sans-Serif';letter-spacing:2px;text-decoration:none;">
             ORDERIN NOW
        </a>
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
```

Which displays like this (in the screenshot):

[you can see it's slightly off-centre towards the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gQeh.png)

Comment: ..could you break the CSS away from the html and make a jsfiddle?

Comment: It would be better if you didn't you inline CSS, we can help you better if your code is clearer

Answer (score 1):

This should render the button without any weird spacing:

```
<p style="margin:0;font-family:'montreal-mediumregular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Tahoma, 'Sans-Serif';color:rgb(70,82,118);font-size:18px;line-height:25px;padding:15px 0 0 0;text-align:center;">
  <br>
  <a href="https://www.orderin.co.za/" style="color:#d3392c;font-size:18px;text-align:center;background:rgb(255,255,255);padding:10px;border:1px solid #d3392c;width:205px;margin:20px auto 20px;font-family:'montreal-demiboldregular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Tahoma, 'Sans-Serif';letter-spacing:2px;text-decoration:none;">ORDERIN NOW</a>
  <br>
  <br>
</p>
```

The text between tags (e.g., `a` tags) should not include trailing space on either end. Browsers handle it differently. On my machine, Firefox strips it all, while Safari and Chrome strip leading, but keep a single trailing space.

When I first pasted your code I got a visible "A with circumflex" character (0xc382) and I cannot replicate. Now when I copy/paste your code I get a space on the *right* (vs your image shows a space on the *left*).

Either way, the corrected HTML above should render normally (tested with Chrome/Firefox/Safari on MBP running High Sierra).